# Postfix relay, how to put the relay in maintenance ? (stop listening to port 25 but finish sending active queue)

Tags: postfix, maintenance

I do use a postfix relay that does some custom mail filtering.

Sometimes this is need for maintenance to disable this relay.

- I need the relay to stop listen to port 25 so that other MX records still process mails to user inboxes
- However at the same time I want active mail queues to be processed (not to make users wait for the maintenance end to receive their mails)

How could that be done ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i guess this can be achieved by setting the `inet_interfaces = loopback-only`  as it controls the incoming connections for postfix or you may also use `inet_interfaces = localhost`

Comment: Thanks, Could be a solution.
Actually wondering how the incomming connections are " blocked ", i.e. if I have a MX1 and a backup MX2, if I set loopback-only, would MX2 server be used instead (as if the MX1 was not responsing). Or would the message just stop when reaching MX1 with a connection refused error...